# Pandas dataframe making multiple rows of headers

Tags: python, pandas

A pandas dataframe I'm trying to use doesn't print properly

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

year = 2021
url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_{}_per_game.html".format(year)
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)
headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]
headers = headers[1:]
rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')] for i in range(len(rows))]
stats = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns=headers)
stats.head(10)

with open('stats.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write(str(stats)
```

in the output it puts the first few headers and rows. then after all the rows are done it does the next set of headers

Answer (score 0):

since you are writing to file, doesn't pandas' to_csv() work for you?

```
stats.to_csv('stats.csv', ignore_index=True)
```

to_csv has quite a few parameterisable options.

Answer (score 0):

I would take Octav's point a little further here. Not only let pandas write to file, but have it parse the table.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

year = 2021
url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_{}_per_game.html".format(year)
stats = pd.read_html(url)[0]
stats = stats[stats['Rk'].ne('Rk')] #<-- removes rows with the "headers"

stats.head(10)

stats.to_csv('stats.csv', index=False)
```